# Random delays in postgreSQL database. Can database replication handle them?

Tags: postgresql, database-replication

**NEW:**

I have to redefine the description of the problem. I checked the statistics of the individual queries themselves with different variants of the extracted data. In general, the individual queries seem to be okay (they do not delay themselves and work well). The problem occurs while the application is running. The application is an internet game.
During one gaming session, new records (with the current state of the game) are constantly being written to the database. A lot of inserts are made at this time.
The user may wish to see the history of the game at any time(while such inserts are in progress).
At this point, when the writing-service is adding new records into the database, the reading-service reads the data. Such reading is very rare compared to writing, it occurs in a ratio of 1:100 (but such reading will occur more often in the future).
This type of reading is delayed.
For this particular problem I think about replication MASTER-SLAVE (writeOnly-readOnly)

The additional information commentator asked about:

```
• Cloud service: gcp
• Service limit: limits:
            memory: 1500Mi
            cpu: 500m
  
• Postgres version: 10
• System log information as to resource usage: I can't get it yet
• Postgres logs information from slow periods: I can't get it yet
• Is cloud service doing automatic database, OS backup: no
• if only 1% of requests are reads, what are the other requests doing: insert new records
```

**OLD:**

Recently i asked about my database problem:  (“Hi everybody, I have PostgreSQL cloud-based database, making 1.5M requests per day, only 1% of these requests are read requests.
The problem is frequent random read delays. Service ugh-read usually reads data in 0-6 seconds. Sometimes the reading time increases to over 40 or even 100 seconds.
Rare jumps like 10-20 seconds would be acceptable, but I absolutely need to get rid of jumps over 40 seconds, especially the number of readings will gradually increase over time.
I consider to make a asynchronous MASTER-SLAVE replication, the master is responsible for writing and the slave is responsible for reading. I’m not sure if is that a good idea?”). One person instructed me to present the problem more specifically. I found methods with delays. I would like to repeat the questions, apparently adding a few details below:

My database resources:

```
resources:
    requests:
        memory: 1500Mi
        cpu: 200m
    limits:
        memory: 1500Mi
        cpu: 500m
```

Service Methods:

```
public Page<UserGameHistory> getGameHistory(String userId, String gameCode,
      String operatorCode, int page, int limit) {
    Validator.from(InputParamsException::new)
        .notEmpty(userId, "User id is not present")
        .notEmpty(operatorCode, "Operator code is not present")
        .notEmpty(gameCode, "Game code is not present");

    PageRequest request = PageRequest.of(page, limit, USER_HISTORY_SORT);
    userId = userIdConverter.fromUnknownToPROPER_NAME(userId, operatorCode);
                                        
    return historyRepository
        .findByUserIdAndGameCodeAndOperatorCode(userId, gameCode, operatorCode, request);
  }

  private UserGameHistory getRoundHistory(RoundRecordDocument round) {
    if (round == null) {
      return null;
    }

    return historyRepository
        .findByUserIdAndGameCodeAndOperatorCodeAndRoundId(round.getInternalUserId(),
            round.getGameCode(),
            round.getOperatorCode(), round.getCycleId(), SINGLE_RESULT)
        .get()
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(null);
  }
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserGameHistoryRepository extends CrudRepository<UserGameHistory, UserGameHistoryId> {

  Page<UserGameHistory> findByUserIdAndGameCodeAndOperatorCode(String userId, String gameCode,
      String operatorCode, Pageable pageable);

  Page<UserGameHistory> findByUserIdAndGameCodeAndOperatorCodeAndRoundId(String userId,
      String gameCode,
      String operatorCode, String roundId, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Entity model:

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = UserGameHistory.TABLE_NAME)
@IdClass(UserGameHistoryId.class)
public class UserGameHistory {

  public static final String TABLE_NAME = "user_game_history";
  public static final String COLUMN_START_TIME_NAME = "roundStartTime";

  @Id
  @JsonIgnore
  private String userId;
  @Id
  @JsonIgnore
  private String gameCode;
  @Id
  @JsonIgnore
  private String operatorCode;
  @Id
  private String roundId;

  /**
  Quantity of other fields:
   5 - String
   5 - Double
   2 - Timestamp
   1 - Boolean
   */
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserGameHistoryId implements Serializable {

  private String userId;
  private String gameCode;
  private String operatorCode;
  private String roundId;
}
```

Comment: Trying to solve a problem you have not identified the cause of is not productive. This is going to need more information. Cloud service and service limit? Postgres version? System log information as to resource usage? Postgres logs information from slow periods? Is cloud service doing automatic database, OS backups? If only 1% of requests are reads, what are the other requests doing? How many concurrent connections and how are they handled, e.g. through a pooler?

Comment: I edited the post, added the information you asked for and actually redefined the problem, could you look again?